# Masonry initialization in angular directive vs vanilla js bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, masonry

I use masonry in one project and I want it initialize in angular directive, but then is there some strange behaviour when window is resizing, and whole grid is pretty buggy. All params are the same.

Pure vanilla JS works ok, but inside angular directive i think that gutter param is omitted.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid1" data-masonry>
  <div class="grid1-item"></div>
  <div class="grid1-item"></div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="grid2">
  <div class="grid2-item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid1-item,
.grid2-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
//not ok
myApp.directive("masonry", function() {
    return function(scope, el, attr) {
        new Masonry(el, {
            itemSelector: ".grid1-item",
            gutter: 20
        });
    }
});

var grid2 = document.querySelector(".grid2");
//ok
new Masonry(grid2, {
    itemSelector: ".grid2-item",
    gutter: 20
});
```

Interesting thing is that if I initialize masonry in angular directive with jquery everything works ok, but I don't want do that on that way.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1u5vm9uo/3/)

How we can avoid that?
Tnx

Comment: Try putting the code inside the directive's `link` function

Comment: Same problem still there: https://jsfiddle.net/1u5vm9uo/3/